# Не совсем понимаю как правильно сделать запрос

Tags: ajax, cors

Возникла необходимость через форму отправить запрос на другой сайт, получить оттуда ответ и вывести на экран. Читал про cors запросы, подойдет ли такой инструмент? И можно работающие примеры подобных запросов.
Есть такой запрос, но как его обработать далее не совсем понимаю

```
 function kbm()
 {
 var KBM_FIO = $('#KBM_FIO').val();
 var KBM_BD = $('#KBM_BD').val();
 var KBM_SERIA = $('#KBM_SERIA').val();
 var KBM_NOMER = $('#KBM_NOMER').val();  
   show_wait();  
  $.post("https://calc.kasko10.ru/check_kbm.php", { KBM_FIO:KBM_FIO,KBM_BD:KBM_BD,KBM_SERIA:KBM_SERIA,KBM_NOMER:KBM_NOMER,domain:document.domain},
              function(data){
                  $("#resultKBM").html(data.body);
                  $("[name='kbm"+kbm_num+"'] option[value='"+data.kbm+"']").prop('selected',true);
                  hide_wait();

              }, "jsonp");
```

}

Comment: а вы думаете кросс-доменный запрос со стороны клиента чем то отличается от обычного? Удаленный сервер должен заголовки выставить, на этом все отличия заканчивается.  В противном случае нужно реализовать свой прокси-скрипт отправки.

Comment: В первый раз столкнулся с подобными запросами просто